# Convergence of a sequence of $2\times 2$ real matrices

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, taylor-expansion

[image]

My Try:

So $a_n$ can be written as a series very similar to the taylor series of sin:

$\displaystyle a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k b_k}{(2k+1)!}$ for some $b_k$ to be determined. But it is very difficult to find a general formula for $b_k$ explicitely. Can anybody please help me to proceed?

Comment: Hint: use Jordan normal form

Comment: If you do not need to calculate the limit, just to show convergence, you may notice that the series converges absolutely (the series of norms is bounded by  $\sinh\|A\|$).

Comment: @A.G.: How do we say that the series converges absolutely without knowing what $b_k$ is?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Maybe absolute convergence is not part of the course and you are supposed to show the element-wise convergence using Jordan form.

Answer (score 2):

Note, that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} x^{2k+1}$ of $\sin(x)$ converges absolutely. Thus $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} \|A\|^{2k+1}$ exists (here $\|\cdot\|$ is the operator norm).

Now you can prove $\|A_n-A_m\| \le \ldots \le \sum_{k=m+1}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!} \|A\|^{2k+1}$ from which you can deduce, that $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence for $\|\cdot\|$. Because $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ is a complete space the sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges under the operator norm.

Because $\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ is a finite real valued vector space  $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in any norm/metric you want to choose...